# Backbone js - Uncaught type error: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have the following a very simple ToDo List app using Backbone framework.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>To do List</title>
    <style>
        .completed{
            text-decoration: line-through;
            color: #666;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/backbone.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>My Todos</h1>
    <div id="tasks">

        <button class="add">Add Task</button>
        <button class="clear hide">Clear All</button>
        <ul></ul>           

    </div>

    <script id="taskTemplate" type="text/template">
        <span class="<%= completed ? 'completed' : 'incomplete' %>"><%= text %></span>
        <button class="complete"></button>
        <button class="delete"></button>
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var Task = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {text: 'New task', completed: false}

        });

        var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Task,
            el: '#tasks',
            initialize: function(){
                this.collection = new Tasks;
                this.collection.on('add', this.appendNewTask, this);

                this.items = this.$el.children('ul');
            },

            add: function(){
                var text = prompt('What do you need to do?');
                var task = new Task({text: text});
                this.collection.add(task);
            },

            appendNewTask: function(task){
                var TasksView = new TasksView({model:task});
                this.items.append(TasksView.el);
            },

            completed: function(){
                return _.filter(this.models, function(model){
                    return model.get('completed');
                });
            }
        });

        var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'li',
            el: '#tasks',
            template: _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),

            initialize: function(){

                this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);
                this.render();
            },

            render: function(){
                var markup = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
                    this.$el.html(markup);
            },

            unrender: function(){
                this.$el.remove();
            },

            events: { 
                'click .add': 'add',
                'click .clear': 'clearCompleted',
                'click .delete': 'delete',
                'click .complete': 'updateStatus',
                'dblclick span': 'edit'
            },

            add: function(){
                    var text = prompt('What do you need to do?');
                    var task = new Task({text: text});
            },

            delete: function(){
                this.model.destroy();
                this.$el.remove();
            },

            updateStatus: function(){
                this.model.set('completed', !this.model.get('completed'));
            },

            edit: function(){
                var text = prompt('What should we change your task to?', this.model.get('text'))
                this.model.set('text',text);
            },

            clearCompleted: function(){
                var completedTasks = this.collection.completed();
                this.collection.remove(completedTasks);
            }

        });     

        new TasksView;

    </script>


    <!-- Template JS -->


</body>
</html>
```

When I visit and load the page, and I could see an uncaught javascript error in the console log.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined** on line 78.

Looking through the code at the indictaed line number, it pointed to this

```
var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    //.....
    initialize: function(){

        this.model.on('change', this.render, this); // this is the line the console is complaining
        this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);
        this.render();
    },
    //.....
});
```

After staring this for the next couple of hours and analysed the code, I couldn't figure out why this model needs to be instantiated when no tasks have been added to the TaskView Objects yet.  It should be initialized as soon as I add or remove a new Task item into the model. I don't quite understand how this would throw an exception.

BTW, I'm a very new to Backbone.js and Underscore.js.  I'm just following an online tutorial to figure out how these frameworks work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding any model to your view. You can pass a model and/or collection when instantiating your new view. These properties will automatically be bound to `this.model` / `this.collection` of your view.

You are not passing a model so `this.model` is undefined in your view. You should pass the empty taskslist so that when it's populated later, the `onchange` will be triggered and your view will rerender.

```
new TasksView({model: new Tasks()});
```

Comment: Thanks @Hazaart.  That should do the trick!.  However, when applying this, and refresh the page.  I get a different console log error. 

It says Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.  This occurs in the his line. this.collection = new Tasks;  Seems like it does massive recursive calls in this collection extends function in a perpetual state... That means somewhere in this tutorial code is not correctly setup....

Comment: @awongCM You are indeed creating a new Collection every time you initialize your collection. You need to remove this line. You should replace all references to `this.collection` to `this` inside your Tasks Collection. As it is already holding the collection in this context.

Comment: Thanks got that one fixed up.  Looks like I encountering more bugs within this tutorial code as I fixed a small bug after the other.  I detect there's a lot of bad code smell in this tutorial bug...

Comment: I am having a similar problem...but I will make only one question(I will create a separate topic for my problem).Did we had to bind a model to a view in backbone 0.5.1 also?Because I used the aforementioned version and the worked without model/view binding