# Backbone.js - Uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Not long ago, I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23823652/backbone-js-uncaught-type-error-cannot-read-property-on-of-undefined) question on Stackoverflow.  Basically, it's my first attempt to try out Backbone.js in my own project, the previous post issue was resolved.

But now, when loading this page up, I could see the following javascript errors printed in the Chrome console window.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: completed is not defined VM46:6
(anonymous function) VM46:6
_.template.template underscore.js:1308
Backbone.View.extend.render example_addbutton.html:69
Backbone.View.extend.initialize example_addbutton.html:65
Backbone.View backbone.js:1031
child backbone.js:1658
(anonymous function)
```

After spending an hour troubleshooting, I traced the problem to this section of the code.

```
<script id="taskTemplate" type="text/template">
    <span class="<%=completed ? 'completed' : 'incomplete' %>"><%= text %></span>
    <button class="complete"></button>
    <button class="delete"></button>
</script>
```

It's suggested the Underscore's templating engine could not comprehend 'completed' variable.

How could that be when I already declare it here?

```
var Tasks = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Task,

            completed: function(){
                return _.filter(this.models, function(model){
                    return model.get('completed');
                });
            },
        });
```

What did I do wrong??

Comment: The error is related to the `template` method, you should pass the `completed` property when calling the template function. Your posted code has nothing to do with the thrown error.

Comment: Thanks! After rereading the code again, I realised there's something wrong with my backbone model declaration with the completed property when passing the variable to the template engine to render.  I'm currently investigating now.  Cheers!

Comment: Tip: you can shorten your `Tasks` collection: since all Underscore collection methods are available in a Backbone collection, you can reduce `completed` to `return this.filter(...); ` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution.

After digging online for quick solution, I had to refactor the so-called 'tutorial' code to get the application working.

Turns out its Backbone View logic was not well written as it tries to render the main app screen as well as a new item added in one section of the code.  So I had to take it out and placed in another Backbone View Logic with the appropriate event listeners.

```
var TasksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',

    template: _.template($('#taskTemplate').html()),

    events: { 
         'click .delete': 'delete',
         'click .complete': 'updateStatus',
         'dblclick span': 'edit'
    },

initialize: function(){
          this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
          this.model.on('remove', this.unrender, this);
          this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
          var markup = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
          this.$el.html(markup);
          return this; 
    },

    unrender: function(){
          this.$el.remove();
    },

    delete: function(){
          this.model.destroy();
          this.$el.remove();
    },

    updateStatus: function(){
          this.model.set('completed', !this.model.get('completed'));
    },

    edit: function(){
          var text = prompt('What should we change your task to?', this.model.get('text'))
          this.model.set('text',text);
    },

});

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#tasks',

    events: {
        'click .add': 'add',
        'click .clear': 'clearCompleted'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new Tasks();
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOneTask, this);
        this.items = this.$el.children('ul');

    },

    add: function(){
        var text = prompt('What do you need to do?');
        var task = new Task({text: text});
        this.collection.add(task);
    },

    render: function(){

    },

    addOneTask: function(task){
        var view = new TasksView({model:task});
        this.items.append(view.render().el);
    },

    clearCompleted: function(){
        var completedTasks = this.collection.completed();
        this.collection.remove(completedTasks);
    }

});
```

And voila!  It works!

Comment: Tip: Think about implementing a `TasksView` and encapsulating the _list_ rendering there (listening for `add` and `remove` on the collection). What's now called `TasksView`, bound to a model, would then render one `Task` (listening for `change` on a model only).

Comment: Sorry... Not sure I quite follow you.  Wouldn't it be the same thing as its original code before I fixed it as above?  Would you be able to demonstrate how to model this code of yours simply?